# Entity Framework success stories?

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework, orm

So like many developers before me, I am at the crossroads of choosing an ORM to learn thoroughly and move forward with for future projects. I have been playing with Entity Framework and so far like what I see, although I have only tried simple things, CRUD with clearly defined table relationships with a 1-1 table-entity mapping.
I did some googling on Entity Framework and found mostly negative feedback... what concerns me the most is the complexity of the mapping xml and generated object classes... As well as the fact that they are dependent on component classes of the EF and therefore need to be respected as such when it comes to object model design considerations. As of now I am leaning towards NHibernate... for the relative simplicity of the mapping files and the fact that it can work with POCO objects that I craft to meet my object model design needs. There is even a LINQ provider for it, as well as third party code generation tools.
However... I don't wish to throw EF out the window just yet. Does anyone know of a successful production app written with EF? Or on the technical side, any reasons I would want to lean towards EF now e.g. has corporate backing, is new and therefore more likely to grow in feature set over time while NH has reached the equilibrium of maturity?
I don't mean to start a color war here, I'm just looking for positive things people may have to add about the EF before I make my decision.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although I tend to agree with Tim about the "religious" element of framework choices, I still find it a bit odd that so many people are willing to comment on the EF when they so clearly haven't bothered to learn how it works. The EF, it turns out, would be a lousy version of NHibernate, just as hammers make poor screwdrivers. It is important to understand the EF on its own terms.

Before I address some of the points raised in comments here, I'll add that we have just shipped version 2 of a production web app with 0 lines of SQL and 100% of all DB access done through either the EF or the ASP.NET membership API to our clients. I speak here with real-world experience with using the EF, something which, regretfully, is clearly not true of the authors of most of the comments on the EF I've seen thus far.

In general, I think it's a mistake to extend your entity types. That the author of the blog post Tim cited (1) wasn't aware it was possible and (2) thinks this is the route to implement DDD tells me all I need to know about his real-world EF experience: *He hasn't got any.*

POCO support became a very big deal to users of certain ORMs because they didn't have a functional LINQ implementation for many years. Since you were essentially stuck with whatever type objects came out of the black box, having control over the parent type became a very big deal. So big, in fact, that writing your "POCOs" with *every member* declared `public virtual` began to be seen as no big deal. On which planet is this a "plain" type? It's a proxy base, not a POCO. The so-called "POCOs" aren't POCOs at all. It's just that they prefer to compromise on encapsulation and performance rather than on parent type. It's probably a legitimate compromise within the limitations of their toolset, but nothing to get cocky about.

But the EF works differently; it's every bit as easy to materialize an arbitrary type via LINQ projections as the type you actually mapped. If you're building something to send objects over the wire instead of to be used internally, and must have clients which can't depend on the EF, then you use RIA services or write an ADO.NET Data Service. All the hard work will be done for you. The EF is the basis for a family of tools handling the problem of projecting data in a DB onto various types of clients, not a single, standalone tool which attempts to handle every single data transformation an app might need internally, in one fat framework. Let the EF handle projection from RDBMSs into object space. You can then use, for example, LINQ to Entities to project into persistence-ignorant types, or RIA services to project onto a Silverlight-friendly wire format. Asking one tool to handle every projection any app might ever need is begging to be stuck in a ghetto with that tool.

The EF is based around the notion of "value objects." These are types with properties but no behaviors. It turns out that value objects work very well for certain specific problems, like sending data over a wire or sitting in the "no man's land" between the RDBMS and OO programming. **It's important to understand the separation of concerns here**: The point of the entity types is to get the RDB **data** into the object space. You can then write business types which implement your app, and project the entity types onto the business types. You then have the freedom to implement your business types with zero compromises for persistence. And you can change your RDB schema when need be. You need only change your entity mapping and BO projections, rather than the BOs themselves.

Comment: Real world experience was what I was looking for;
In the end it may make sense to separate entity classes from behavior classes, although after reading up on Rockford Lhotka's CSLA framework and even writing my own "ORM" inspired by it, I became pretty attached to the idea of self containment when it comes to logic encapsulation. It looks like the EF would be best in service oriented apps where the app logic lives on the service, but I still need data objects to send to the client... EF entities fit this perfectly, and can be sent/received by the logic objects service side.

Comment: **The so-called "POCOs" aren't POCOs at all.** If you think about it, non-virtual properties are not plain too, you can put behavior in there, i.e. you can put code in there :-) Where property is the mechanism for an ORM consumer to put intelligence to a model, a virtual property is the mechanism of an ORM makers to put intelligence to their ORM offering. Loading (using session.Load<entityHere>(idHere)) an object from NH is very intelligent, has no performance penalties, it just uses the stub(doesn't hit the database) when you want to use it in many-to-many relationship.

Comment: The only time the NHibernate's stub object hit the database is when you access its properties other than its id. To some uninitiated EF users, they tend to use what's out-the-box, they will tend to use db.Ent.Find, thinking there's no mechanism to use stub on EF, there is, but it's a world of hurt, you need to detach the stub object if you want to access the real object

Comment: Mapping the EF entities to your own custom entities is pretty much throwing away all of the features of EF, lazy load, dirty tracking, identity map.. e.g. if you ask your own custom UoW for one of your BO objects, you will need an ID map. if you alter properties on your BO object, you might need to do some funky dirty tracking in order to update the underlying EF object...  I'm not saying this is the wrong approach, for complex models I do this too, but there are some pain to it.. in many cases, it is enough to just partial class extend the EF objects and use those for your domain..

Comment: "haven't bothered to learn how it works". I have bothered to learn how it works, but I found I must adjust everything else to serve EF rather than EF serving me. If I have performance problems, "Oh, you need to learn how EF works". Bull. EF is slow and for many, many scenarios simply a bad choice. I sought help from a back end expert who recommends EF but he could not easily look at my code and tell me how to do it right... he just gave general advice that didn't help. Then I learned he uses dedicated EF developers. What?! If you need dedicated EF devs then there is a problem with EF imho.

Answer (score 5):

I got rid of Entity Framework 4.1 and never used it again for the following reasons:

- The official documentation sucks. There is little to no information on how and why things work the way they do. No examples for anything beyond basic CUD scenarios. For example, I have 5 related tables and a single atomic operation (a transaction) is supposed to delete records from 2 of them, then add one record to the 3rd, and then update the last 2 with the ID from the one that was just added. I can clearly see what SQL is required for doing this. Now in the Entity Framework it is a mystery what sequence of manipulations on the data context can get me to the same result.

There are good articles and blogs of enthusiasts who know it in and out, but hey, its not the same as looking up in a reference and why would I expect anybody to know it better than the official document from the official source? And why doesn't Microsoft bother giving its flagman data-access technology a better manual that covers how-to's that go beyond their first-grade-book examples? The lack of information on how to use it makes the learning curve steeper that results in wasted time and missed deadlines.

- There is no way to get inside of it and see what it is trying to do. **It's a very well-built black box.** Despite of advocating for using IoC and dependency injections, teams in Microsoft rarely follow these principles in their own products. The entity framework is not an exception. Most of the core classes are marked as sealed (EntityConnection, MetadataWorkspace) so you cannot override a method and see what is going on inside. The ToString() method works only with the queries. If you want to see the real SQL statements generated by stacking your POCO's to the data context and running SaveChanges, forget about it, there is no way of doing it. Ironically there is no notion of a changeset at all, so something that encapsulates a series of modifications is buried in the internals and never exposed to the developer. I mean there is nothing to call the ToString() on when it comes to CUD operations.
- "Friendly" error messages. Almost every error message is a puzzle that takes on average 30 minutes of googling and reading discussions of frustrated developers. Why is it so hard to put some information that can help to troubleshoot problem right into that darn error message? How is "An error occurred while getting provider information from the database." better than "Unknown error"?
- I don't feel I am in control over what is going on and where I am at each particular moment. The entities can be lazy loaded, cached, or pulled out of the database per an explicit request. And I cannot tell by looking at the object what state it is in or where it originates from. Is it stale, dangling, or event attached to the context? Will Entity Framework make sure it's still in the database when I link it to another entity? All you are exposed to is your POCO objects, conventional collections  and few additional methods in the DbContext. Wait, is the IDbSet (akin ICollection) interface a superset of all operations the database is capable of? Wouldn't it be more fair to admit that the database is something slightly more complex and hence requires special interfaces and additional objects that could clearly communicate the intent? Given that the Entity Framework does more than just pulling and pushing the data, wouldn't it make more sense to have something like `Cached<TEntity>` and `LazyCollection<TEntity>` that tells you the story at the time you look at it? The attempt to squeeze the ADO.NET into ICollection and interfaces alike sacrificing vital details for the simplicity wasn't a smart idea. It hurts the ease of understanding and makes more room for unintended mistakes. I mean the object model needs to reflect the domain closely. You cannot ignore it or hide the differences in static methods of the Database class.

All in all I spent more time trying blindly all different ways to make it work instead of focusing on the real problem. I found out that even though ADO.NET requires lot more typing the result is guaranteed in a finite (and not horribly bad) time, while with the Entity Framework you can spend a couple of days yet don't get anything. And this is a huge deal breaker. So the bottom line is: Entity Framework doesn't help you to solve your business problem. It helps you to waste your time in a constant fight with yet another poorly designed/documented technology just for the sake of using it and joy of using the LINQ syntax for simple queries. Don't risk your time, it's not worth it. If you have plenty of time, go ahead and try it, it's a good excuse for a higher bill to your client.

**UPDATE:**

On a positive note. On my next project I will give a try to the Entity Framework 5.0. Thank God this time we have the source code :) So now it doesn't look as bad.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this type of question is that there is an element of "religion" in peoples choice of frameworks, and ORM's inspire quite a lot of passion.

So at the risk of certain flames...I personally am not a huge fan of the Entity Framework, I can see where it would be pretty good to take a legacy system and ER model and map it, but I think in the longer term (and my use case) is more built around a Domain Model design and for my Entities to be mapped to that. There is a nice [blog post](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2008/02/13/ddd-with-ado-net-entity-framework.aspx) here that I tend to agree with.

I think that I like the approach that products like NHibernate and [Eco](http://capableobjects.com/) take. And currently I am experimenting with a true OODBMS (instead of an ORM) with [DB4Objects](http://www.db4o.com/) and am very impressed so far.

Comment: I bet EF v4 will please you more - support for true POCO, domain-driven design and more. The current version is indeed a ..... compromise :-) at best.

Comment: DB4O is amazing. The speed both in queries as in devtime are just mindblowing. I didn't experiment with a client/server architecture yet so I can't judge on that, but I am rather confident in that. If only my boss was as excited about it as I am :P

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Wait until EF 4.0

Long answer:

I'm wrapping up a medium-sized EF 1.0 project now (also ASP.NET MVC).  I also have experience with NHibernate.  Aside from the common CRUD mappings, we did quite a bit of inheritance modeling.  Overall my feelings about it are mixed.

A few observations:

The best thing I can say about EF 1.0 is that it has great LINQ integration.  It is better than Linq to NHibernate (in its current release).

EF can handle the interesting inheritance mappings well, but you turn up A LOT of mapping errors trying to get it right.  The documentation isn't super helpful here and there isn't yet a lot of community support.  You just have to figure it out.

The designer is buggy and doesn't support everything the EF can do.  You often find yourself editing the XML mapping files by hand.  The designer creates errors in otherwise correct mapping xml.  In fact, we've had so many issues with the designer that we'll go into the XML first, rather than let the designer update the mappings. I'd say this is a problem I have with Microsoft products in general: they build products with geared toward tooling rather than libraries.   In this case, they rushed the tooling because the XML is equally bad.

The XML is, er, verbose. EF 1.0 requires a lot of mapping information.  Contrast NHibernate's XML, which only deals with the mapping itself and doesn't require a conceptual definition or storage definition file, or, better yet, a tool like Fluent NHibernate, which lets you specify your mappings in code.

I, personally, prefer to write classes that can themselves be persisted (POCO) rather than deal with a separate data entity model.  Craig's point about public virtual notwithstanding, I prefer NHibernate's proxy approach.  I have to disagree with Craig on the intent of the EF.  I don't think they intend that you create a mapping layer between the EF and your business objects.  As partial classes, the intent seems to be that you add behavior to your entities in order to create a full OO class. With that in mind, you can't unit test EF 1.0 without jumping through a lot of hoops.

Perhaps the biggest irritation with EF is the lack of transparent lazy loading.  That truly sucks.

I will wait until EF 4.0 comes out before I willingly use it again.

Comment: You're irritated with not having lazy loading because you're trying to user entity types directly instead of projecting. When you project, all the loading is handled automatically instead of having to eager load or explicitly call Load. Of course it hurts to swim upstream. The question is why you're so convinced that those of us floating downstream on inner tubes are doing things wrong while you struggle and curse.

Comment: Craig, you'll have to point to some examples of the approach you're advocating. Creating a mapping layer between my POCO objects and EF isn't exactly floating downstream and it isn't in keeping with the direction from the ADO.NET team, who advocate partials to add behavior to entities -- and EF 4.0 is going POCO.  As for lazy loading, even with your approach you run into loading issues when using inheritance where subclasses may have divergent navigation properties.

Comment: I have a talk on this coming up at the free, online CodeRage conference in about a month from now. Tune in if you're interested. Mapping entities to business types *is* easy with LINQ, it's just that users of other ORMs aren't used to working this way. Sorry, you're just flat wrong about subtypes; that's trivial in LINQ. I do understand that developers unable to use LINQ would find this difficult, but they'll just need to catch up.

Comment: Ok, well I'm no expert but I feel pretty comfortable with LINQ.  EF->POCO projections is usually easy enough, but POCO->EF I'll wait for your talk. I'm not sure what lazy loading has to do with LINQ.  I'm talking about within the EF.  Let's say you have a supertype Order and two subtypes: CustomerOrder and EmployeeOrder where CustomerOrder.Customer and EmployeeOrder.Employee are divergent navigation properties.  If you then have an IEnumerable<Order> with both types, you will have to check ((CustomerOrder).CustomerReference.IsLoaded and handle appropriately.  How does LINQ help you with that?

Comment: What LL has to do with LINQ: It's entirely automatic; **L2E coalesces nulls**. Presuming that, for the sake of argument (your app may be entirely different; this is a representative example), that the reason you want Customer and Employee in a single list is to get at the related Person from o in Context.Orders let c = o as CustomerOrder let e = o as EmployeeOrder select new { Order = o, Person = o.Person ?? e.Person }. In short: Don't think in terms of materializing entities; that's the way ORMs stuck with one type work. Think in terms of materializing the info your BOs actually *need*.

Comment: "o.Person ?? e.Person" should read "c.Person ?? e.Person". Mea culpa.

Comment: So, your argument is that my BO has the abstract Order AND the typed Order's (CustomerOrder/EmployeeOrder) divergent properties? In your example, the project is an anonymous type, but I would likely use typed BOs...like CustomerOrder or EmployeeOrder. Now I'm back to mapping a behavioral class to a value class - basically using an internal state object with change tracking. Without the ORM/LINQ, I'd have passed in the data to the behavior class's constructor: CustomerOrder(CusomterOrderInfo info). Now I'd have to manage a separate, parallel object graph of state. This isn't floating.

Comment: I think the way you're using 'entities' is confusing.  Do you mean 'don't think in terms of materializing BOs'?  Entities are just stateful objects with identity not determined by the values of properties.  That's just what an ORM is in the business of materializing/persisting.

Comment: Projecting to a non-anon type is just as easy as projecting to an anon type. "Entity" in the **Entity** Framework has a precise and rather obvious meaning, as distinct from "entity" outside of the EF. Read "subtype of EntityObject" if you prefer, but that's hard to fit in a length-limited comment. Mapped types (whether "POCO" or not) are not the same as BOs (separation of concerns); treating them as the same is bad design. Yes, it's harder to track changes if you project to *true* POCOs (not proxy bases), but I'll pay that price for clean separation of concerns and no runaway state in the app.

Comment: I hope you won't mind me linking to your own blog post related to this discussion: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2008/07/17/37825/
Although over a year old now, it may add value for a reader of this thread.  

The problems with the designer corrupting the edmx are frustration in EF 1.0 (EF 3.5).  I'll keep an eye out for your presentation.

Comment: Craig, having had a chance to watch your presentation, I thought I'd append a link and some thoughts. The talk (http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/09/11/38394/) was very interesting and I really like the implications of projecting onto the business objects for testing and OO encapsulation. However, I think the objections concerning mapping from your POCOs back to the EDM still stand. Without change-tracking in your POCOs, you have to build custom mapping to your data access layer. Whether that's a worthwhile trade-off should be understood up-front by anyone following your approach.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using NHibernate at InterWorks for 4 years now.  It has worked great for us and we have built another layer on top of it to simplify usage (similar to Castle ActiveRecord, which we were unaware of at the time).

The downsides of NHibernate is the learning curve, lack of a strong GUI tool(we use our own MyGeneration templates to generate objects), and OK community support.  We have put a lot of effort into making it work for us and have spent quite a bit of time training new team members on NHibernate and the framework we have built around it.

Since we build mostly custom software, it is hard for us to justify the overhead of rebuilding our framework, but most likely in the next two years we will move to the Entity Framework for a couple of very basic reasons.  (1) Better documentation and larger support community (it will happen quickly) and (2) Easier to find people with experience in EF, thus eliminating some training costs.

Those are not true today, but they will be pretty quickly with the next release of EF in VS.NET 2010. It has really matured and with the built in VS.NET support it is coming around nicely.  We've done some basic tests with it, but I do not claim to have extensive experience with EF.

It to MS a while to get with the program, but now that they have the EF will be here for a long time to come and will become the standard.  If you don't have experience in either ORM, I would start learning EF, it will be better for your career in the long run.